# How to limit the results of recognition?

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

how to restrict the results of [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) **(Tesseract and Leptonica library)**,
 
I want Tesseract limiting the results:

1. Only take 8 digits, calculated from letter **D**
2. Don't take **LowerCase, Enter, Space, and Symbol**
3. Only Take **Uppercase and Numbers**.

**For Example:**
 
The recognition result is **"asn*&bhDK 1234 UDaks&%^jdg"**, then simply take is **"DK1234UD"**.
so, don't take LowerChase, Enter, Space. Only take UperChase and numbers.
**I use Java source code**

this is the recognition code:

```
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_AUTO_OSD);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    //setImage
    baseApi.setImage(bmpOtsu);
    //set whitelist
    String whitelist = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, whitelist);
    //variable for recognizing      
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    String resultTxt = recognizedText;
    baseApi.end();

    if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
        recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]", " ");
    }
```

Can somebody tell me how can i do that? What should be added in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx to @Yazan for the answer and it's work.
and i've improve the answers.
this is my code:

```
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_AUTO_OSD);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    //set variable
    String whiteList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    String blackList = "\\s";
    baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, whiteList);
    baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, blackList);
    //setImage
    //baseApi.setImage(bmpOtsu, w, h, 8, (Integer) null);
    baseApi.setImage(bmpOtsu);
    //variable for recognizing      
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll(blackList, "");//remove space
    String resultTxt = recognizedText;
    //
    baseApi.end();

    Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);
    if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
        int get8digits = recognizedText.indexOf("D");
        String loop = recognizedText.substring(get8digits, recognizedText.length());
        if(recognizedText.contains("D") && loop.length() >= 8){
            Log.w(TAG, "OPSI 1"+"\n"+"Length: "+loop.length()+"\n"+"Values: "+loop);                
            recognizedText = recognizedText.substring(get8digits, get8digits+8);                                                
        }else if(recognizedText.contains("D") && loop.length() < 8){
            Log.w(TAG, "OPSI 2"+"\n"+"Length: "+loop.length()+"\n"+"Values: "+loop);
            recognizedText = loop;
        }else{
            Log.w(TAG, "OPSI 3"+"\n"+"Length: "+loop.length()+"\n"+"Values: "+loop);
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[A-Z0-9]"," ");

        }
```

I hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 3):

if you use instance of `TessBaseAPI`, you can call `setVariable()` with constant `VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST`

```
String whiteList = "ABCD...XYZ1234567890";
tessBaseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST,whiteList);
```

you can tune the white list based on your needs
so if you want to ignore all other letters except D and K, set it:

```
String whiteList = "DK1234567890";
```

you might still need to do more string manipulation on the result if needed,
like removing letters from end of result, as based on your example
you may get this as result (using second whilteList)

```
DK1234UD
```

**EDIT:**

To Get result from : DK123455UD
you can use substring()

```
String result = "DK123455UD";
int pos = result.indexOf("DK");
String finalResult = result.substring(pos,pos+8);
```

**EDIT:**
**Like This ?**

```
    String whitelist = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, whitelist);
    //setImage
    baseApi.setImage(bmpOtsu);
    //variable for recognizing      
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    //
    int get8digits = recognizedText.indexOf("D");
    String resultTxt = recognizedText.substring(get8digits, get8digits+8);
```

Comment: letters which definitely is "DK". The letters after the "DK" is not fixed. 
so, sometimes after the letters **DK** is **1234UD**, or **4369CU**, or **0987BA**.

Comment: yes, thats why i told you, you need to manipulate the final result to get what you want, maybe apply some regExp to extract pattern starts with DK followed by any numberic digits, thats what you need to do, if the white list gave you what you need

Comment: based on your question:**Only take 8 digits, calculated from letter D** so at final result, get indexOf("DK"); and substring 8 digits...

Comment: but how can do that? can you tell me with java code? please... really confuse

Comment: i have added `setVariable` in my code, look at above. but now, how can limits only 8 digits of results start from letter **"D"**

Comment: i have edited the question, added a sample, also i noticed you used all letters in whitelist but you mentioned earlier that only 8 letters from DK.

Comment: i have edited the answer, have added the code your provided. right or wrong? tell me please...

Comment: it's work, but still get **"space"** and **"ENTER"** from result. how to not take **SPACE** and **ENTER** ? because if the result contains a space, then the space is also calculated.

Comment: i added code `baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "\n");` it's not work, and then added code `baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, " ");` still not work to remove **SPACE** from result recognition. can you help me please.....